# API wrong WITHDRAWAL Fee

Tags: coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm developing a application to monitor Transactions on Coinbase. I developed my interface to ease of use. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but all my withdrawals are with wrong Fee's. I what to give to the user the real fee of a withdrawal, but if I use the accounts/:account_id:/transactions no fee is available to the withdrawal, I have to call again with the resource url, but then I get the fee under network, and this value is only from the network gas fee. Who can I get the full fee?

For example, I transferred 0,54938902 ETH from coinbase to another exanger, according to the API the fee was 0.00103950 ETH, but in reality the fee was 0.00259477 ETH, because 0.54679425 ETH was the actual value to enter at destination.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a minute to read [How to ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, all is good, the problem is that this particular destination exchange charges deposit fee...